# How to connect to a Oracle Database from Web Services Published on IIS

Tags: .net, oracle, web-services, iis

The situation is this:
1. Oracle database 10g on one server. Configured to accept connections.
2. Web service on different server (IIS), connecting to the database. This doesn't work.
3. Same web services running on the VS 2005 web server, work without a problem and can connect to the database.

The problem:
Do not know what is the issue with web services published on IIS in respect to connect to Oracle 10g when the same services, running on VS 2005 web server work without the problem.

Error returned: Oracleclient connection timedout.

Answer (score 0):

So the database is on machine A and the web server that cannot connect is on machine B.

Where is the web server that can connect?  If it is not on machine B, then what are the differences in network location/configuration between these two machines?

On machine B, can you telnet to the Oracle server on Oracle's listener port?